# Eloquent: relationships between blog tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

someone would have a practical example of using relationships in Eloquent as follows: I have a blog with several categories, in these categories I will have several Posts, as I do to display a category with several Post in Views. Any practical examples for me to study my logic? I've seen several here, but none fit into what I want above.

Model Post:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');

    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;
use App\Category;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex() {

        $posts = category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        return view('v1.index')->withPosts($posts);
        // $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
        // $categorias = Category::find(1);
        // return view('v1.index')->withPosts($posts)->withCategorias($categorias);
    }


    public function getContact() {
        return view('v1.contato');
    }

    public function postContact(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'min:3',
            'message' => 'min:10']);

        $data = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
            );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('hello@devmarketer.io');
            $message->subject($data['subject']);
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Your Email was Sent!');

        return redirect('/');
    }


}
```

Model Category:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

View index

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="home-slider">

        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="post feature-post">
                <div class="entry-header">
                    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('imgs/'.$post->image) }}" width="572" height="350"  alt="" />
            <div class="catagory world"><a href="#">{{ $post->category->name }}</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h2 class="entry-title">
                        <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div><!--/post-->
        @endforeach



    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems you are already displaying all posts related to a category. So what is the issue/question ?

Comment: @EddyTheDove,Thanks for answering.
Example: I have a blog with a slide, where I want to display 6 Posts in a category and hide the first 3 Posts. My question, how should I get my Controller and view to do this ..?

Comment: You should get the `$post` you want to display first. Then get all the posts of the category `$posts = $category->posts;`. Send them to your view `return view('v1.index', compact('post', 'posts'));`. Is it what you are tyring to do ? but limiting `$category->posts` to 6 only ?

Comment: This, in fact I have a slide, in this slide I want to show 6 Posts of a category hidden the first 3 Pots, I want to show this in my main page of the blog. I'm not sure how to do Foreach to show it on my slide

Comment: Try `$slidePosts = Post::where('category_id', $category->id)->skip(3)->take(6)->get();`

Comment: return messenger: Undefined variable: category

Comment: It means you need to get the category first. before that line, do `$category = Category::find(1);`

Comment: It looks like it's going to work, and how does the code on the view look like for me to view?

Comment: Ok I make a full answer for you. If it works, accept it as the answer.

Comment: Okay. I'll wait. Thank you for dedicating yourself to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the category you want to display

```
$category = Category::find(1);
```

Then Get all the post related to that category by skipping the first 3

```
$posts = Post::where('category_id', $category->id)
->skip(3)
->take(6)
->get();
```

Pass them to your view

```
return view('v1.index', compact('posts'));
```

In your view, wherever you want, loop them with blade exactly the way you are doing already.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

@endforeach
```